# How to share junk mail lists between multiple computers?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have multiple computers running Microsoft Outlook 2010 and 2013. Is there a way to share a black and white list for junk mail, so I don't have to setup those lists in every computer? Plus, I would be nice to share new additions on those lists, as every user includes new entries on their respective computer.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but Sue Mosher's site is an awesome resource for this - http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/using-outlooks-junk-mail-filter/

Comment: [How to import and export safe / blocked senders list?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1386-outlook-import-export-safe-blocked-senders-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can deploy Junk Email settings using Group Policy. Microsoft [KB2252421](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2252421) describes the process in details and provides GPO ADM files.